# post/parse canvas image data from nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, post, http-post

I have been trying to submit an image being rendered on a html canvas to a nodejs http server however im having an issue parsing the submitted form on the recieving end:

```
ipcMain.on('resizeOK', (event, arg) => {
  if(currentImage){
  var formData = {
    my_field: 'my_value',
   // my_file: fs.createReadStream(imagepath), - old way using a local path
    my_file: currentImage, //new way using the data from an image canvas
    my_width : arg.widthData,
    my_height : arg.heightData,
    my_quality : arg.quality
  };

  request.post({url:'http://localhost:8080/resize', formData: formData}, function optionalCallback(err, httpResponse, body) {
  if (err) {
    return console.error('upload failed:', err);
  }
  console.log('Upload successful!  Server responded with:', body);
});
}
});


// how the image is retrieved from the current canvas
var currentImage = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");


//HTTP server being posted to
if (req.url == '/resize') {
    var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
    form.parse(req, function (err, fields, files) {
      var output = util.inspect({fields: fields, files: files});
      var newWidth = fields['my_width'];
      var newHeight = fields['my_height'];
      var quality = fields['my_quality'];
      res.write('File uploaded to '+output + "");
      res.end();
    });
  }
```

After reading a number of articles it seems many have attempted the same thing however in pure javascript not in nodejs : http://www.nixtu.info/2013/06/how-to-upload-canvas-data-to-server.html

however the example here makes use of BLOB which is unavailable directly in nodejs.

The current error i recieved now is a "write after end" server response, which has only occured after swapping out submission of a standard image via a local image path with the uri-data from the canvas element.

Is there a simple way to post my data-uri and parse it back into a usable js object on the http nodejs server?